# Problem installing haskell-platform

Tags: linux, haskell, installation, haskell-platform

I'm trying to install Haskell (for the first time). Following the instructions on the website, I downloaded:

- ghc-6.10.4-i386-unknown-linux-n.tar.bz2
- haskell-platform-2009.2.0.2.tar.gz

I unpacked the ghc package, and installed it without problems. Then I unpacked haskell-platform and run the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
su
make install
```

I get this error:

```
**************************************************
* Building each component completed successfully.
*
* Now do "sudo make install"
**************************************************
milanb@slicky:~/install/haskell-platform-2009.2.0.2$ su
root@slicky:/home/milanb/install/haskell-platform-2009.2.0.2# make install
scripts/install.sh
Installing mtl-1.1.0.2...

Error:
The mtl-1.1.0.2/Setup script does not exist or cannot be run
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

What to do next?

Comment: Why not use your package manager? `apt-get install ghc6`, for example.

Comment: Because I use Slackware.

Comment: Asking at super-user? Come on guys, do you really expect that I'll get answer for this there? Imagine someone having trouble to set up MS Visual Studio... would you send him there as well?

Comment: You'll get a great answer at superuser ... "Ask this on Stack Overflow" .. and let the volleyball game BEGIN :)

Comment: Did you manage to get it fixed? I've run into similar problem and, just as yourself, don't know what is next. Please, update this thread if you've got any luck.

Comment: @artemave: no, I'm also evaluating lisp and it worked out-of-the-box, so... I might try Haskell later, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the most relevant link: http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/ticket/84

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the cause is, but I think it is better reported to the Haskell Platform mailing list and bug tracker:

- http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/report/1

Answer (score 0):

just check out this link, it will show "how to install Haskell on various platforms" in easy way..

these 2 links are to my blog only.. i think these links will be useful for you..

http://akashjagdhane.blogspot.in/2013/02/installing-all-packages-of-haskell-so.html
http://akashjagdhane.blogspot.in/2013/02/installing-ghc-with-all-packages-on.html